# Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $a^{p^{p-1}}\equiv a$ $(mod$ $p)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My attempt:
From Fermat's Little Theorem, we have $a^{p}\equiv a$ $(mod$ $p)$, and by raising both sides to the power of $p-1$, we have $a^{p^{p-1}}\equiv a^{p-1}$ $(mod$ $p)$. But I don't see how $a^{p-1}\equiv a$ $(mod$ $p)$.

Comment: When you raise by a power of $p - 1$, your LHS is $a^{p(p - 1)}$, not $a^{p^{p - 1}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You powered up wrong; $(a^b)^c\ne a^{b^c}$. Rather, note that
$$p^{p-1}\equiv1^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p-1$$
and so by FLT
$$a^{p^{p-1}}\equiv a^1\equiv a\bmod p$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get how you got the second equation from the first equation.

Comment: @Charlie It's all powers, and didn't I write Fermat's little theorem there as justification? We look at the power first, then apply it in the original equation.

Comment: But isn't one equation mod p-1 one mod p? How can we combine those? I am sorry I think I'm a little dumb...

Comment: @Charlie We are working in the exponent regime. The modulus accordingly changes.

Comment: @Charlie The congruence modulo $p-1$ serves to show that the exponent $p^{p-1}$ can be written in the form $k(p-1)+1$ for a certain integer $k$, which one can and must furthermore argue is positive (i.e. a natural number). It follows that $a^{p^{p-1}}=\left(a^{p-1}\right)^ka$, which brings you in a position to apply the particular form of Fermat's little theorem, for $a \notin p\mathbb{Z}$ (the remaining case will have to be discussed separately, but it is immediate).

Answer (score 3):

As others have already indicated, you have made a mistake with the exponentiation. The phenomenon of interest here is described by the following:

> **Proposition.** Let $p$ be a prime number and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ an arbitrary integer. Then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the congruence $m^{p^n} \equiv m\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$ holds.

*Proof.* The natural way to prove this universal statement concerning natural numbers is by induction. In the base case $n=0$ we trivially have $m^{p^0}=m^1=m$, so the congruence modulo $p$ trivially holds. Considering an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and assuming the claim to be valid for $n$, we raise the congruence $m^{p^n} \equiv m\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$ to the $p$-th in order to obtain:
$$m^{p^{n+1}}=\left(m^{p^n}\right)^p \equiv m^p \equiv m\ (\mathrm{mod}\ p),$$
where the latter congruence is justified by Fermat's little theorem. $\Box$

---

At this stage you might not be entirely familiar with the concepts I am about to mention, but in a more brief presentation what happens here is that the Frobenius automorphism of the residue field $\mathbb{Z}_p\colon=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ -- given by elevating to the $p$-th -- is the identity automorphism, and therefore any of its powers of generic exponent $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in the group of automorphisms are alse equal to the identity. These powers are however in general given by raising to the $p^n$-th, and this is precisely the content of the above proposition, in veiled form.